# npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote in React.js

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I tried different ways about 3 days but my react project don't work. When i pulled code from GitHub repository, i taken this error, i removed `node_modules` then i run `npm install`. My project still don't work. Could you please help me?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: You use `npm cache clean`. After, you remove `node_modules`. Finally, you run again `npm install`. Did you try?

Comment: Yes i tried all of them, do you know another way?

Comment: Did you install `Git`?

Comment: I see that `ls-remote -h` command is Git. `npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
` error message tell us that there is not Git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+npm+ERR%21+enoent+undefined+ls-remote

Answer (score 3):

```
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
```

The above error message tells us that we need to install [`Git`](https://git-scm.com/downloads). After installing Git, you try again `npm install`.

Comment: thanks for your help .my problem is solved :)